# C# - Class Library Project - Unable to update App.config file while building the project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, build-definition

I have a C# based Selenium project which has an app.config file. This app.config file has sensitive information which should NOT be made available in the code explicitly.

Is there a way to pass in the password to the app.config file before building the project.

The password can be supplied in the Build settings ( in variables section ) and can be made hidden.

Is there a way to read the values from the Process variables tab and update the values in the app.config file before building the project?

Or is there a way to send the password in an obfuscated/encrypted fashion using C#?

I cant user Replace tokens build step due to some constraints ( since it is a custom marketplace extension ) If there is a task by Microsoft which helps me in this scenario.

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Comment: what do you mean before building the project?

Comment: If you have proper build script created using msbuild you can inject this step.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch - I believe app.config file needs to be updated before the dll is generated. This means to have something before the msbuild task in the build process.

Comment: Before the build generated, you have to update the app.config file? just for the sensitive content?

Comment: @VijunavVastivch - yes. This is a sensitive content. Thats the only reason

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - I am using the msbuild task , Is there a provision available to over ride the values in app.config file using this task??

Comment: @TimothyRajan Hi, is there any update? As far as I know, we have no msbuild task is for updating app.config. But not sure if a [pre-build-event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-use-build-events-in-msbuild-projects?view=vs-2019) or [Exec Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2019) can meet your needs, since what you want is to update your app.config before building project.

Comment: Maybe you can consider writing a .exe or .bat (which will read value from certain places and update app.config), and add a 'call xxx.exe' or 'call xxx.bat' in project=>properties=> prebuildevent. But have to say, for the security you want, maybe vijunav's suggestion(machine registry) can help.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT - I did many things. Nothing worked. At last I just encrypted the password and read from a REST service. Decrypted and ran it. It would be good to have a official Microsoft task similar to replace tokens rather than to get it from markteplace. Thanks for your idea/help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did many things. Nothing worked. At last I just encrypted the password made it available as a REST service. Invoked the service while running my test and Decrypted and ran it. Thanks all for your work on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is just to secure Password am i right?

1. You can save your password into the machine registry to be hidden and encrypted.
2. You can use an external services to provide your secured password if we are talking about `securing the password` (Web Service or something).

This is just a suggestion. Just think about it.

Comment: I will explore option 1. This sounds very achievable. Will keep posted.

Comment: i did no 1 many times for my past projects deployed and i did not encounter any problem when it comes to password security.